# Python - Partially Duplicate Rows - Keeping only the last one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

We have this code:

```
data = [['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '5:15:00', 4.792e-05, 4.8e-05, 4.777e-05, 4.783e-05, 30027.0], ['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '5:30:00', 4.79e-05, 4.817e-05, 4.78e-05, 4.811e-05, 10151.0], ['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '5:45:00', 4.788e-05, 4.811e-05, 4.764e-05, 4.767e-05, 9682.0], ['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '6:00:00', 4.766e-05, 4.796e-05, 4.759e-05, 4.761e-05, 22046.0], ['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '6:00:00', 4.766e-05, 4.796e-05, 4.759e-05, 4.761e-05, 22094.0], ['BQXBTC', '9/14/2018', '6:15:00', 4.761e-05, 4.77e-05, 4.761e-05, 4.763e-05, 26761.0], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '2:15:00', 0.001712, 0.001718, 0.001711, 0.001713, 9065.28], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '2:30:00', 0.001712, 0.001718, 0.001712, 0.001716, 11504.56], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '2:45:00', 0.001717, 0.001719, 0.00171, 0.001711, 10365.09], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '3:00:00', 0.001712, 0.001721, 0.001709, 0.001716, 8922.49], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '3:00:00', 0.001712, 0.001721, 0.001709, 0.001714, 8924.85], ['ETCBTC', '9/14/2018', '3:15:00', 0.001716, 0.001718, 0.001709, 0.00171, 14429.7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

returning this:

```
         0          1        2         3         4         5         6         7
0   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:15:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  30027.00
1   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:30:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  10151.00
2   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:45:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048   9682.00
3   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  6:00:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  22046.00
4   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  6:00:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  22094.00
5   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  6:15:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  26761.00
6   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:15:00  0.001712  0.001718  0.001711  0.001713   9065.28
7   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:30:00  0.001712  0.001718  0.001712  0.001716  11504.56
8   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:45:00  0.001717  0.001719  0.001710  0.001711  10365.09
9   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  3:00:00  0.001712  0.001721  0.001709  0.001716   8922.49
10  ETCBTC  9/14/2018  3:00:00  0.001712  0.001721  0.001709  0.001714   8924.85
11  ETCBTC  9/14/2018  3:15:00  0.001716  0.001718  0.001709  0.001710  14429.70
```

The problems are the (partially) duplicate rows:

1) Rows 3 and 4 come at the same date and time for that symbol, but the volume (col 7) is slightly different.

2) Rows 9 and 10 come at the same date and time for that symbol, but the close (col 6) and volume (col 7) are slightly different.

The logic to fix this would be:

If there is more than one row with the same col 0 (symbol), col 1 (date) and col 2 (time), 
count only the last row, dropping the previous one/s.

This is the desired output:

```
         0          1        2         3         4         5         6         7
0   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:15:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  30027.00
1   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:30:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  10151.00
2   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  5:45:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048   9682.00
3   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  6:00:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  22094.00
4   BQXBTC  9/14/2018  6:15:00  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  0.000048  26761.00
5   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:15:00  0.001712  0.001718  0.001711  0.001713   9065.28
6   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:30:00  0.001712  0.001718  0.001712  0.001716  11504.56
7   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  2:45:00  0.001717  0.001719  0.001710  0.001711  10365.09
8   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  3:00:00  0.001712  0.001721  0.001709  0.001714   8924.85
9   ETCBTC  9/14/2018  3:15:00  0.001716  0.001718  0.001709  0.001710  14429.70
```

How do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0,1,2], keep='last', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect.. thank you very much. BTW, say we're not using Pandas and just want to do the same thing with a csv. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @FrankC assuming the CSV was properly sorted, you could set up a dictionary with the tuple of symbol, date and time and update for each row you see accordingly. It's much easier with pandas though!